# Как в vba проверить, что ссылка указывает на существующий экземпляр объекта?

Tags: vba, ms-access, visual-basic

Допустим, в коде было создание экземпляра формы 'info':

```
Set f = New Form_info
```

Затем где то в коде идет обращение к объектной переменной f, например:

```
MsgBox f.Caption
```

Если пользователь уже закрыл к этому моменту форму "info", возникнет ошибка.

Проверка на Nothing:

```
If f is Nothing Then
...
EndIf
```

не помогает. Переменная f к этому моменту всё ещё ссылается на объект (который уже не существует).

Я делал обработчик ошибок:

```
On Error GoTo FormClosed:
MsgBox f.caption
...
FormСlosed:
...
```

Так, конечно, работает. Но этот вариант (с On Error) мне не нравится. Ведь должна же быть какая то стандартная проверка?

Comment: А форма реально создается в нескольких экземплярах? Если нет, то лучше форму не создавать через New и проверку на существование формы можно делать так: `SysCmd(SYSCMD_GETOBJECTSTATE, A_FORM, "frmMyForm")`

Comment: Спасибо, как контролировать "стандартные" формы, я знаю. И даже как "отловить" экземпляры форм. Здесь объект form приведен для наглядности. Вопрос касается "висячих указателей" вцелом, можно ли как то проверить существование экземпляра произвольного объекта.

Comment: На sql.ru Сергей Вакшуль публиковал менеджер форм, который отслеживает все открытия-закрытия, сохранение данных. Посмотрите там.

Answer (score 1):

При открытии нескольких экземпляров одной формы лучше хранить переменные ссылок на них в едином массиве или коллекции, а при закрытии пользователем формы удалять соответствующий элемент в собылии OnClose или OnUnload.

Для проверки существования формы, если известен конкретный уникальный признак формы (например Tag или Caption), можно просто перебрать коллекцию Forms, а не обращаться через переменную с непроверенной ссылкой.

Более детально про работу со ссылками на нестандартные формы можно почитать [здесь](http://www.sql.ru/faq/faq_topic.aspx?fid=240)